# load-on-startup problem tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to load a class on tomcat startup which will actually initialize variables in other classes.

i have edited the appName/WEB-INF/web.xml as follows

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoadConfigurations</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Loader.LoadConfigurations</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>env</param-name>
      <param-value>dev</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

and i have placed my servlet LoadConfiguration in /appName/WEB-INF/classes

how do i check whether the servlet is beig called or not ? because when i try to display the value from initialized class it returns null

Comment: try keeping logs or System.out.println("Inside Constuctor") inside constructor and init() method start and end. check if you are getting the logs.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

1. The compiled class needs to go into a folder structure base on the package name. In your case a folder called `Loader`
2. In order to call the servlet, you need to add a `<ServletMapping>` to your `web.xml` file

Answer (score 1):

The container should call your servlets init() method when the servlet is initialized. Implement/override that method and try writing something to the log from there.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fix it on tomcat 9:

1. Edit the `conf/context.xml` file and add `reloadable="false"` to the `<Context>` tag.

   `<Context reloadable="false">`
2. Edit the `conf/server.xml` file and add `deployOnStartup="false"` to the `<Host>` tag.

   `<Host appBase="webapps" deployOnStartup="false" …>`

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for Tomcat 7.0

Step 1:
  Create war file  for your webapp/servlets.
  If you are using Eclipse, File->Export->Web->WAR file, and save it to a known location.

Step 2:
  Find out the home folder for your tomcat.
  For that, go to tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/bin and execute ./startup.sh
  This will print out couple of global variable names.
  Note down the one for CATALINA_HOME.

Step 3:
  Copy the war file from Step 1 in CATALINA_HOME/webapps

Step 4:
  Next, Create an xml file in CATALINA_HOME/conf/{Engine}/localhost/MyServlets.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<Context deployOnStartup="true" docBase="/home/ubuntu/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/" reloadable="true">
<Manager pathname=""/>
</Context>
```

Change docBase to point to location where you copied the war file in Step 3.

Now, you can go go to tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/bin and execute ./startup.sh.
Your servlets will be automatically started.
Hope this helps.